# Finding value of $\sec(\pi/4)\sec(\pi/8)\sec(\pi/16)...$ using Centre of mass of half ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass

So I made this question on my own and my method is-

We know COM of half ring is at $2R/\pi$ distance from geometrical centre along axis of symmetry (let this be $y$-axis and diameter perpendicular to it be $x$-axis)

Now observing the 2 quarter circles,
The quarter circles will have COM on their axis of symmetry i.e. at angle $\pi/8$ to the y-axis. Also, the $y$ coordinates of COM both the rings will be same and equal to $2R/\pi$ due to symmetry of the $y$ coordinate and therefore distance between COM and centre is $2R/\pi \sec(\pi/4)$

Continuing this on by further splitting the obtained ring pieces into symmetrical halves,

distance of  from centre COM- $2R/\pi(\sec(\pi/4))(\sec(\pi/8))(\sec(\pi/16))\cdots$

and when angle tends to zero position of COM will tend to $R$

Therefore, 
\begin{align}
\frac{2R}{\pi}\cdot\sec\left(\frac\pi4\right)\cdot\sec\left(\frac\pi8\right)\cdot\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\right)...&= R \\
\sec\left(\frac\pi4\right)\cdot\sec\left(\frac\pi8\right)\cdot\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\right)...&= \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

So, is this correct or incorrect with reasons supplied for both?

[image]

Comment: This is a question about [math.se], not physics. The only connection with physics is *centre of mass* but that concept is irrelevant here. When you say centre of mass you mean *centre of area*.

Comment: Well sorry, i am just a high school student, and i don't know about centre of area.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to obtain this is to use $$\sec x = \frac{2\sin x}{\sin 2x}= \frac{\text{sinc} x}{\text{sinc} 2x},$$so $$\prod_{n=2}^\infty \sec\frac{\pi}{2^n}=\prod_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\text{sinc} \frac{\pi}{2^n}}{\text{sinc} \frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}}=\frac{\text{sinc} 0}{\text{sinc}\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: sorry, but I am still in highschool and don't know the sinc function

Comment: @IamLearning $\text{sinc} x:=\sin x/x$. If you prefer, you can do the argument using sines.

Comment: @IamLearning also, $\mathrm{sinc} 0$ is defined as $\lim\limits_{u\to0} \sin u/u = 1$. Or, if you like, $\mathrm{sinc} $ is the function defined by $\mathrm{sinc}  u = 1 - u^2/3! + u^4/5! - u^6/7! + \cdots$: which is the same as the function $ \sin u/u $ with the singularity removed.